# Adding constraint on whole row based on primary key usage

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have two tables

**Table_1**

| PK ID_Table1 | IsDeletedValue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |

**Table_2**

| PK ID_Table2 | SomeValue | ID_reference_from_table_1 | IsDeletedValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Text1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Text2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Text3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | Text4 | 3 | 1 |

Now i want to set a constraint on "Table 1" to prevent change of "IsDeletedValue" based on 2 things:

1. "IsDeletedValue" from "Table 1" cant change if the ID is referenced in "Table 2"
2. "IsDeletedValue" from "Table 1" cant change if the row refrencing it has "IsDeletedValue" set as "0"

So now in my scenario if i were to try and set the value of "IsDeletedValue" to "1" on all rows from "Table 1" the following would happen

Row 1 - STAYS AS "0" - Since its PK is referenced under "ID_reference_from_table_1" and in that same row the "IsDeletedValue" is not set to 1

Row 2 - CHANGES TO "1" - Yes its PK is referenced in "Table 2" BUT the only row referencing it has its own "IsDeletedValue" set to "1"

Row 3 - STAYS AS "0" - Its referenced 2 times but since not all rows referencing it have their "IsDeletedValue" set to "1" it will not change

Row 4 - CHANGES TO "1" - Is not referenced in "Table 2" so there is nothing to prevent it from changing

**EDIT**: Since im being told this cant be done how to i write a select statement (that returns "true" or "false") to see if ID_Table1(n) is used in a row from "Table 2" where "IsDeletedValue" is 0 (AKA the value of "IsDeletedValue" from "Table 1" cant change)

Comment: You would need to write before update trigger which should contain the logic.

Comment: .. Constraint cannot solve - it can access only the columns values of the same rows, not of another row or another table.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by checking if the following select returns any results:

```
SELECT a.ID_Table1
FROM Table_1 a INNER JOIN Table_2 b 
ON a.ID_Table1=b.ID_reference_from_table_1
WHERE b.IsDeletedValue=0 AND a.ID_Table1=?
```

and i send ? as a parameter ID from Table_1 to know what row i am editing